# how to use Poiret One font

Tags: fonts, xetex

how can I use poiret one font for just 2 or 3 lines (and not the whole text)? Is there a command like `\textsf{word}` for poiret one font type?

Comment: Good question, and welcome to the site! Unfortunately, the polite comment by Mensch directing you to the earlier answer appears to be gone.

Comment: Following  "How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?" I solved my question like this: ```{\fontfamily{\poiretonefamily}\selectfont  <<text>>}```. Thanks